# How to properly structure flutter project with API & Local data storage?

Tags: flutter, dart, project-structure, project-structuring

So i have created some apps in flutter with laravel backend, which works online only. Now i need to make an app work offline as well for which i am thinking of using Hive. But now the problem is i cannot find a good resource on how to properly manage such large project. My past projects were mostly small, but with local storage and all, i want to use interfaces & repositories to manage the project. But i can't figure out how to put everything together so the code is manageable.

So can someone help me here? Is there any such project that i can study, or perhaps even an article or a video. Anything that sheds light on how to structure large projects in flutter will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

There is no right or wrong on how to structure your Flutter project. You can put everything in a single file. Also it depends on the package its being used, for example I use BLoC as state management and these are some project structures that the package recommends:

- [Flutter Architecture Samples](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/tree/master/bloc_library)
- [Brian Egan Flutter Shopping Card](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_shopping_cart)
- [Example Flutter TDD Course - ResoCoder](https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course)

I don't use any of those, I made my own project structure that I will explain in a moment. There's a [package layout convention](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout) for Dart (not for Flutter projects).

I use the following structure:

```
├──lib/
│  ├──blocs/
│  ├──models/ 
│  ├──repositories/
│  ├──screens/
│  ├──utils/
│  ├──widgets/
│  └──main.dart
```

I separate everything in folders so front-end devs can work on the widgets folder where there is all the design stuff and back-end devs can works on the blocs folder where there is all the logic.

Remember there is no wrong or right answer. Check-out your recommended project structure that your favorite state management package recommends or watch this talk: [Keep it Simple, State: Architecture for Flutter Apps (DartConf 2018)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKXz3pUkw9A)

Comment: is it necessary if we add more cubits folder if we also want to use cubits?

Comment: @AriefWijaya Yes you can, after the cubit release I create a state management folder and put all the files with this naming convention: file_cubit.dart or file_bloc.dart

Comment: Could you please explain what repositories should stand for?

Comment: @PhiliposD. Here are some links that may help:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=repository